# Removing and adding quotes from each string in an array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I want to remove and add quotes in array string.

I am trying **this**.

```
dataPoint[shardIndex] = '{y:'+actualSize+', '+'label:'+shardName+'}';
```

`var datapoint` returns **following result**.

```
Array(3) [ 
     "{
          y:33.33282469150909, 
          label:shard1
      }", 
     "{
          y:33.33282469150909, 
          label:shard2
      }", 
     "{
          y:33.334350570415694, 
          label:shard3
      }" 
 ]
```

`var datapoint` returns above but I want the following *result*.

```
[
  {
       y:33.33282469150909, 
       label:"shard1"
  }, 
  {
       y:33.33282469150909, 
       label:"shard2"
  }, 
  {
       y:33.334350570415694, 
       label:"shard3"
  }
]
```

Comment: set it equal to an object literal? `dataPoint[shardIndex] = {y: actualSize, label: shardName}` ?

Comment: I didn't get your mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are adding strings in your array. Instead, you should add objects.

The correct syntax for this should be.

```
dataPoint[shardIndex] = {y: actualSize, label: shardName};
```